# Eclipse DDMS does not show contents of sdcard

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

File Explorer of Eclipse shows an sdcard folder for both an Android emulator and an Android device.  However, it does not show any contents of the folder.

Does this sdcard folder corresponds to an SD Card?  If so, how can the files on SD Cards be viewed with DDMS?

Comment: Check /mnt/shell/emulated. If you are on a 4.2+ device the sdcard is located in a folder named "0"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am going to guess that by "an sdcard folder" you mean `/sdcard`. That has not been the location of external storage in quite some time.

Depending on the version of your Android emulator/device, you can look in `/mnt/sdcard/`, `/storage/sdcard0/`, or `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, it is /mnt/sdcard/.

Comment: In Android 6.0 it does not show contents of `/mnt/sdcard/` anymore, yet DDMS allows for copying a file to the folder. I wonder how to copy a file from `/mnt/sdcard/` to PC?

Comment: @Stan: Android 6.0 uses `/storage/emulated/0` instead of `/mnt/shell/emulated/0`.

Comment: It does not allow to expand `/storage/emulated/`.

Comment: Here is the question about the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254072/sdcard-content-not-visible-in-ddms-file-explorer-android-6-0. A solution is wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

Using Eclipse DDMS File Explorer the content of sdcard was not visible in any folder (CyanogenMod with Android 4.2.2).

The solution was:
On the device you have to give ADB root access. Here: Settings / Developer options / Root access

Then the content of sdcard is visible in this folder:
/mnt/shell/emulated/0